# PHP curl talking to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: php, rest, curl, dynamics-crm, odata

I am trying to pull some data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online, which resides on remote host;
it works if I manualy (from browser) log in and exec my from my server which runs PHP on Linux host, but of course i want to authenticate and run CRUD operations without my mediation :) .

But it keeps on showing me "Object moved to here." page for authentication.
If i set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1, it shows login page of crm.

If anyone can suggest any clue for resolving situation... thanks!

```
<?php

$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
$urlValue  = "/LeadSet?$select=Address1_City,FirstName,LastName";

$username  = "domain\user";
$pass      = "pass";


$handle = curl_init();    
curl_setopt_array($handle, 
        array (
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $useragent,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD   => $username . ':' . $pass,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH  => CURLAUTH_ANY,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_URL  => 'https://myhost.com/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $urlValue,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        )
);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

header('Content-Type: text/plain;');
print_r($response);
```

Comment: does it really use *http authentication*? My guess is that it doesnt, because you say it redirects to a login form, and generally when your browser is presented with an actual login form in html, the resulting state of being logged in is maintained via cookies, not http authentication. make sure.

Comment: @chris he is not scraping. He is using [Odata REST API for Microsoft Dyanmic CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx). It uses [Basic authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192997.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I solve da problem make an authentication by ntml, this code shows how to retrieve contacts from CRM in JSON format.

```
$url='http://<server_adress>/organizationName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet';
$ch = curl_init();
 $headers = array(
      'Method: GET',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
      'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Host <server network adress>');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '<user>:<password>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//echo $response; 
$array=json_decode($response, true);
$size=count($array['d']['results']);
echo "Numero de registos:".$size."<p>";
echo "Contactos:<p>";
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
 echo "Nome: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['FullName']."<p>";
 echo "Cidade: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['Address1_City']."<p>";
 echo "Emprego: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['JobTitle']."<p>";
 echo "Morada: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['Address1_Name']."<p>";
 echo "Telefone: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['Address1_Telephone1']."<p>";
 echo "Email: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['EMailAddress1']."<p>";
 echo "Pais: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['Address1_Country']."<p>";
 echo "Codigo-postal: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['Address1_PostalCode']."<p>";
 echo "Criado por: ". $array['d']['results'][$i]['CreatedBy']['Name']."<p>";
 echo "...................................................................................<p>";       
}
```

If somebody knows how to make crud operations in rest endpoint please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that i have answer to my own question, what i am trying to achive is not possible, because of this:
**Authentication is only possible within the application**.

As noted here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279

And i am trying to authenticate from remote site.

Answer (score 1):

Does adding the following CURL option help?

```
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_NTLM
```

It did the trick for me. Apparantly, the server to which I am connecting does not support basic HTTP authentication but enforces NTLM. Might help in your case.

Comment: was thad microsoft dynamics 2011 crm ? I tried NTLM also. But that did not help. At the end i resloved the problem using SOAP connection library

Comment: Yes, that was with Dynamics 2011. Are you able you connect to the rest interface with your web browser, by the way? It might help to sniff what authentication your web browser is using (that was how I found out that I should use NTLM authentication).

Comment: I needed this to operate automatically without my interference, so i gave up that approach anyway. Thanks for clues, thouguh. I tried to use Fiddler a bit.